# Distinct count not giving expected result

Tags: crystal-reports, concatenation, alert

I have fields for customer names, customer account numbers, date of previous orders, and order values. I want an alert to show which customers have ordered at least three times over the reporting period. We can have more than one invoice for a given delivery. The main report looks like:

```
Account Number  Acct Name   Order Date   Order Total
1001            Fred Smith  1/2/2016     £1.06
1001            Fred Smith  1/2/2016     £2.34
1001            Fred Smith  8/2/2016     £5.42
2001            Aled Jones  1/2/2016     £2.90
2001            Aled Jones  8/2/2016     £3.45
```

I've tried concatenating the account number and order date in a column via function and running an alert based on its distinct count. (After converting the date to a string.) But it still doesn't generate a list of distinct items.

What I currently have in the final column is a function that concatenates the date and account number to give a unique field with `{ORDR.CardCode} + Cstr({ORDR.DocDate})` - Which returns:

```
1001 1/2/2016
1001 1/2/2016
1001 8/2/2016
2001 1/2/2016
2001 8/2/2016
```

I want to generate alert based on this field via the distinct count function and a report of any customer who ordered at least twice in the report period.

```
DistinctCount ({@Concat code and date}) >2
```

Even after this I still don't get what I need. How can I get a list of every customer who has ordered in the report period for at least two times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have travelled half way... to achive continue from here.

USe the created formula `{ORDR.CardCode} + Cstr({ORDR.DocDate})` to create a group.

place same formula in details and take count of the records in group footer

Now create a alert on group footer summation to get the desired result

Edit........

Since you need customer then add customer in concat fornula and then create group.

`acctnamr+{ORDR.CardCode} + Cstr({ORDR.DocDate})`

Now place the customer name in group header and follow process as explained above

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not certain I'm doing it right.  I've got to the following:

        Account Number   Account Name   Date     Total       Concat Code and Date
        100101/02/2016
        1001             Fred Smith     1/2/2016 1.06        100101/02/2016
        1001             Fred Smith     1/2/2016 1.06        100101/02/2016
                                                                                                           1

Is that right so far please?  I get a summary of one, but scratching my head on the alert part.  Cheers!

Comment: Hmm, that formatting didn't work.  Anyway, I get it grouped, but I get a summary of 1 on each group using 'distinctcount' and the alert on the formula above aimed at the group footer generates a list that's exactly the same as the one I'm taking from.

Comment: Take count not distinct count...will work tested solution

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing this wrong or not explaining myself.  The basic report to take the information from will be five weeks long.  I need to know if a customer has ordered on three delivery days in that five week report, and throw up an alert to say so, but they can have multiple orders on a given delivery day.

What I'm getting is a number of times they've ordered on each delivery day, which isn't what I need.  I need to know how many of the concatenated account number/date combinations are in the document and if there are more than two for a customer, it says who that customer is.

Comment: Thanks for the help - got something that looks like it working!  You're a gent :)

Comment: No problem happy to help